# Export text in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, export

I need to export some data into a text file. I have searched a little and I can't seem to find anything useful and recent. I'm already using pdfkit and csv to export data to pdf and csv files, so I don't know if I can use any of these to make the text. Anyone had this problem and found a solution recently?

**EDIT**

My question is a little vague, I'll specify more. I need to do something like CSV.generate does. Add rows for every value of the attribute in the register. I find the register, I store it in a variable, and then I need to "add" every value as a row in the textfile. The part of make a loop through the attributes of the register found I got it working, what I don't know is how to copy it. That's the part where I'm stuck.

**EDIT 2**

I ended up passing an array of all the attributes of the register and saving it in a local variable, then I did what you suggested and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick search:
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37888

```
@content = "Hello World"
send_data @content,
  :type => 'text',
  :disposition => "attachment; filename=your_file_name.txt"
```

see also  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html

Comment: I've seen this, and it's a little more complicated than that. I need to copy the values of a register from the database into a text file. Every row in the textfile will be a value of the register. That's the part that got me stuck

Comment: what if one wants to Export the contents in page?

Answer (score 1):

In order to export/write something inside text field. first you need to open text file with write mode and then need to write data to it.

```
file = File.open("/home/sandip/myfile.txt", "w")
file.write "this is how text file can be written"
file.close

file = File.open("/home/sandip/myfile.txt")
file.read #=> this is how text file can be written
```

If you need to export database records to csv file then make use of csv library its pretty straight forward.. [click here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its similar to other file format - export

Try like this

```
def download_textfile
  @content = get_content
  send_data @content,:type => 'text',:disposition => "attachment; filename=file_name.txt"
end
```